# Getting incomplete xml data from web-service

Tags: android, xml, web-services, http, post

I am sending a POST request to a web-service which returns data in XML format. When I invoke the web-service via the browser i can see the complete XML file. However, when I call the web-service from my android app (in emulator) I only get partial XML data?

The size of the XML file being sent is approx 14500 bytes. I first store the response in a byte array whose size i calculate using `getContentLength()` function. This method returns the correct size of the response.

However, my `InputStreamReader` reads approximately 6350 bytes of the actual data to the byte array. The remaining part of the byte array simply contains zeros.

I tried looking everywhere online but so far I haven't come across a solution. Yes chunking is one option but since I dont have access to the web-service code I can't implement that option.

Really appreciate if someone could guide me here!

Comment: Could you post us some code, important to know if you're using HttpClient or URLConnection and which version of the android API you are targeting as the Android docs admit to bugs in the URL connection code pre-honeycomb.

Comment: @Elemental unfortunately i dont have access to the code right now....i will share it shortly. I am using HttpClient and i am targetting Android 2.2 platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why do you need to use InputStreamReader (which can behave very wrong if you are not careful) to read web service data (in your case it is only around 14.5kb). Just use HttpURLConnection, connect to your ws, and it will take care for you about the connection and also the response `connection.getResponseMessage();`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I used HttpURLConnection but still the issue persists. Although the number of bytes returned by the srevice is 16500 approx the BufferedReader.readLine() method only reads upto 6851 bytes. Can you suggest what else may be wrong here?

Comment: yes the HttpUrlConnection option worked for me! Thanks Anh Tuan!!